# Reading strings from resource file in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi

I have a resource file named ELEMENTS.RC that starts like this (it contains instructions in several languages).

```
    STRINGTABLE {
    1, "רגיל"
    32001,"Instructions"
    32002,"La situation"
    32003,"Vos actions"
    32004,"Explication de vos actions"
    33001,"Инструкция" 
    }
```

The above RC file is compiled to RES format with GORC and is linked into my executable.

I have created a simple form containing one Tlabel. Here is the code that I am trying to use

```
    procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    var
     len: word;
     buffer: pwidechar;

    begin
     len:= loadstringw (hinstance, 32001, buffer, length (buffer));
     if len > 0
      then label1.caption:= buffer
      else label1.caption:= inttostr (GetLastError);
    end;
```

// Edit that changes the question!
The following code does read id 32001 from the resource file. But I want it to read id 1 from the file (there is supposed to be a value) and this is failing. Is there a tool that can read compiled resource files (res)? Hopefully the use of such a tool will find the problem with some of the strings.

Code that works:

```
    function LoadResW (id: integer): WideString;
    const
     maxlength = 1024;

    var
     len, i: integer;

    begin;
     setlength (result, maxlength);
     len:= loadstringw (hinstance, id, pwidechar (result), length (result));
     if len > 0 then
      begin
       setlength (result, len - 1);
       if pos ('~', result) > 0 then
        for i:= 1 to len - 1 do
         if result[i] = '~'
          then result[i]:= '"';
      end
     else result:= '';
    end;
```

Comment: `LoadString` is a WinAPI function, and hasn't changed since it was introduecd. The only difference in the Delphi versions would be that by default Delphi 2009 and above use the Unicode variants of the API call rather than the Ansi versions.

Comment: Could you write a small .RC file and short program that reproduce the issue and add those into your question. I will then try your code and try to understand what is wrong (With Delphi 10.4.1 Sidney).

Comment: Have you tried to change the type of ``buffer`` to ``AnsiChar``?

Comment: The last parameter of `LoadString()` is expressed in characters, not bytes, so change `sizeof()` to `length()`. Also, the return value of `LoadString()` does not include the null terminator, so the loop `index` is going out of bounds of the returned string data, so use `len-1` instead. And if `LoadString()` returns 0, use `GetLastError()` to find out why

Comment: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: There's definitely something peculiar in my program, as a test program (very simple) using the above LoadResW function reads and displays the required strings from the resource file. I'm going to use the above mentioned resource hacker in an attempt to establish what is wrong. I'm also going to develop the test program so that it can replace the buggy part of my program.